# How to output binary search method?

Tags: java, search, binary

This is just your average binary search, in my program I use this search method to allow the user to look for book titles.

```
String [] binaryArray = {"4", "6", "10"}; //the chosen binary numbers to look for

public static Boolean binarySearch(String [] A, int left, int right, String V) {
    int middle;
    Boolean found = false;

    while (found == false && left <= right) {
        //If middle item == 0, returns true
        middle = (left + right)/2;
        int compare = A[middle].compareTo(V);
        if (compare == 0) {
            found = true;
        } else {
            if (compare >0) {
                right = middle -1;
            } else {
                left = middle + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (left > right) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I choose IF statements to output the correct response,  but imagine if the database was for a real library with possibly millions of entries.  This obviously would not work very well. So what is way a way I can find the response needed without IF statements? Any ideas or advice would be appreciated!

```
private void findBookActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //finds book...                                       

    String input = enterNumberField.getText(); //input number to see if it matches up

    if ("4".equals(input)) {
        binarySearchField.setText("Book Title" + binarySearch(binaryArray, 0, binaryArray.length-1, "4"));
    } else if("6".equals(input)){
        binarySearchField.setText("Book Title" + binarySearch(binaryArray, 0, binaryArray.length-1, "6"));
    } else if("10".equals(input)){
        binarySearchField.setText("Book Title" + binarySearch(binaryArray, 0, binaryArray.length-1, "10"));
    }
}
```

Comment: binarySearchField.setText("Book Title" + binarySearch(binaryArray, 0, binaryArray.length-1, input)); ???

Comment: Well that hardly makes a difference since I'm scratching that out of the code

Comment: For a real library you probably won't be using an Array. So, no binary search either. You'll be fetching just the book your user wants from the DB using SQL.